# regularity of Borel summation

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation-method

How do I prove that the Borel summation of an arbitrary convergent series,
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k
\end{equation}
defined as
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\frac{t^k}{k!}dt
\end{equation}
always converges to $S$? To be clear, I want to know how to prove it when the series is not necessarily absolutely convergent.

The Wikipedia article on Borel summation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation#Regularity) justifies switching the order of the integral and the sum with "absolute convergence". Am I just missing something or was it only proving it for taylor series on the interior of an analytic disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the sequence $b=b_1,b_2,..$ satisfy $b_n \to 0$ and let $f_b(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_ke^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!}, t \ge 0$ (which is trivially absolutely convergent for a fixed $t$).

We claim that $f_b(t) \to 0, t \to \infty$. This is a standard proof and I will append it at the end, but now I want to show how this implies the required Borel convergence.

Assume $\sum a_n \to A$ and as usual let $s_n=\sum_{ k\le n}a_k \to A$ its partial sums.

Also as is standard in the theory of Borel convergence we call $\alpha(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k \frac{t^k}{k!}, \beta(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}s_k \frac{t^k}{k!}$ and we note that $\beta'(t)-\beta(t)=\alpha'(t)$

Applying the result above first with $b_n=s_n-A \to 0$ we get that $e^{-t}\beta(t)-A \to 0, t \to \infty$, while applying it with $b_n =a_n \to 0$ also, we get $e^{-t}\alpha(t) \to 0, t \to \infty$

A simple integration by parts shows that:

$e^{-t}\beta(t)-a_0=\int_0^{t}d(e^{-r}\beta(r))=\int_0^{t}e^{-r}\alpha'(r)dr=e^{-t}\alpha(t)-a_0+\int_0^{t}e^{-r}\alpha(r)dr$

Using the above and letting $t \to \infty$ we get that $\int_0^{t}e^{-r}\alpha(r)dr \to A, t \to \infty$ which is exactly

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\frac{t^k}{k!}dt =A
\end{equation}

so we are done up to the simple fact regarding $f_b$ in the beginning

To prove that $f_b(t) \to 0, t \to \infty$ we pick $\epsilon >0$ and $N=N(\epsilon), |b_n| \le \epsilon, n\ge N$.

Then $|\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}b_ke^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!}| \le \epsilon\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}e^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!} \le \epsilon$ independent ot $t$ and then we can pick $t>T(\epsilon)$ s.t each of the missing terms in $f_b(t)$ so $b_ke^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!}, k=0,..N-1$ is at most $\epsilon/N$ in absolute value since $e^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!} \to 0, t \to \infty$ for each fixed $k$. Putting all together, we get $T(\epsilon)$ s.t $|f_b(t)| \le 2\epsilon, t \ge T(\epsilon)$ and we are done with this part too!